# CREATE LOGIN for AD user in master not allowing connection

Tags: sql-server, azure

I am struggling to figure out the best method to set up security on an Azure SQL Managed instance. First, I tried to set up SQL logins, but since MUST_CHANGE isn't supported, I would then have access to everyone's password when I created the login, clearly an unacceptable solution.  I then made myself the AD admin, and set up AD accounts.  If I CREATE USER <user_name> FOR EXTERNAL USER in the master database, people can connect, but if I CREATE LOGIN <user_name> FOR EXTERNAL USER and then perform the CREATE USER commands in the other dbs linking to the login, people still get a login error.

Since I cannot define a DEFAULT_DATABASE on the CREATE LOGIN command, I am really confused about the security context.  Am I really supposed to create users for everyone in the master database?  That seems like a security hole.  Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to change the containment option first before you can create a contained user in Azure SQL Managed Instance. It is done by default for the Azure SQL database.

> Azure SQL Managed Instance behaves like SQL Server on-premises in the
> context of contained databases. Be sure to change the context of your
> database from the master database to the user database when creating
> your contained user. Additionally, there should be no active
> connections to the user database when setting the containment option.

Example code:

```
USE MASTER;
GO 

ALTER DATABASE Test
SET RESTRICTED_USER
WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE;

ALTER DATABASE Test
SET containment=partial;

ALTER DATABASE Test
SET MULTI_USER;

USE Test;  
GO 

CREATE USER Carlo  
WITH PASSWORD='Enterpwdhere*'  

SELECT containment_desc FROM sys.databases
WHERE name='Test'
```

Reference: [Contained Database Users - Making Your Database Portable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/contained-database-users-making-your-database-portable?view=sql-server-ver15)

Comment: So it turns out that once you create a user with an AD account, and associate a USER to that LOGIN, they DO have access.  I'm not sure why it wasn't working for me.  Some type of weird caching issue is all I can figure out.

Comment: I thought you wanted to create a contained user (without login in the Master database).

Comment: Ah, I understand.  I didn't want to create USERs in the master database.  Logins I could understand, because they can't do anything in master other than connect.  I appreciate you comment regarding contained databases, but there was something else strange going on that seems to have been gremlins in the system.